# Adding lines with labels to indicate change on a graph using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following image and I want to re-create it in LaTeX using Tikz.

[image]

So far, I've got something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-2,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};
    \draw[scale=1,domain=-2:2.5,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{(e^\x) / 4});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I add the delta x and delta y in the visual with color?

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. *Coordinate system perpendicular* in the [Ti*k*Z and PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) should help (syntax with `|-` and `-|`). This is page 141 in version 3.1.4b of the manual. For the delta x and delta y, use the `node` operation. Ugh, this is automatically-generated code...

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. I just updated my post. I think I have the lines down, but there is still some discrepancies with where I'm at.

Comment: I'm taking a closer look at your reference. It seems to answer my question. I'll post a follow up with the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to automate the drawing of these “delta things” for any function and make it parametrizable:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\tikzset{
  myDelta/.cd,
  xmax/.initial=10, % This has to be set in the picture (one can't guess here)
  ymin/.initial=0,
  text x/.initial={$\delta x$},
  text y/.initial={$\delta y$},
  label style/.style = {color=black, font=\normalfont\scriptsize},
  x label style/.style = {below}, % allows overriding for the x label
  y label style/.style = {right}, % allows overriding for the y label
  line style/.style = {thin, dashed, color=green!60!blue},
  % Convenient shortcuts for appending keys to the previous styles
  labels/.style={/tikz/myDelta/label style/.append style={#1}},
  x labels/.style={/tikz/myDelta/x label style/.append style={#1}},
  y labels/.style={/tikz/myDelta/y label style/.append style={#1}},
  lines/.style={/tikz/myDelta/line style/.append style={#1}},
}

\newcommand{\drawDelta}[4][]{ % <-- Spaces here don't matter because this is
  \begingroup                 % <-- used in the tikzpicture (and not in node
  \tikzset{myDelta/.cd, #1}   % <-- texts).
  \edef\xMax{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/myDelta/xmax}}
  \edef\yMin{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/myDelta/ymin}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\valuei{#2(#3)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\valueii{#2(#4)}
  %
  \draw[myDelta/line style]
    ({0.5*((#3) + (#4))}, \yMin) node[myDelta/label style,
                                       myDelta/x label style]
      {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/myDelta/text x}}
    ({#3}, \yMin) -- ({#3}, \valuei) -- (\xMax, \valuei)
    (\xMax, {0.5*(\valuei + \valueii)}) node[myDelta/label style,
                                             myDelta/y label style]
      {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/myDelta/text y}}
    (\xMax, \valueii) -- ({#4}, \valueii) -- ({#4}, \yMin);
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\normalfont\scriptsize,
                    declare function={f(\x) = exp(\x)/4;},
                    myDelta/xmax=4, myDelta/ymin=0]
  % Set up a little shortcut
  \edef\xMax{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/myDelta/xmax}}

  \draw[->] (-2,0) -- (\xMax,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw[domain=-2:2.5, smooth, variable=\x, red!90!black] plot (\x, {f(\x)});

  % Rely on the default values for the first (delta x, delta y) drawing
  \drawDelta{f}{1.1}{1.2}
  % Override or complement the default values for the second one
  \drawDelta[lines={thin, color=blue!20, solid},
             labels={fill=blue!20, rounded corners},
             x labels={yshift=-2pt},
             text x=$\Delta x$, text y=$\Delta y$] {f}{1.8}{2.3}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following. Suggested improvements are appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-2,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};
    \draw[scale=1,domain=-2:2.5,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{(e^\x) / 4});

    \draw[red] (1.0, 0) -- (1.0, 0.679570457) node[above] {};
    \draw[red] (1.1, 0) -- (1.1, 0.751041506) node[above] {};
    \draw[red] (1.0, 0.679570457) -- (4.0, 0.679570457) node[above] {};
    \draw[red] (1.1, 0.751041506) -- (4.0, 0.751041506) node[above] {};

    \draw[purple] (2.0, 0) -- (2.0, 1.847264025) node[above] {};
    \draw[purple] (2.1, 0) -- (2.1, 2.041542478) node[above] {};
    \draw[purple] (2.0, 1.847264025) -- (4.0, 1.847264025) node[above] {};
    \draw[purple] (2.1, 2.041542478) -- (4.0, 2.041542478) node[above] {};

    \draw[red] (1.05,-0.2) node(dx1) {$\delta x$};
    \draw[purple] (2.05,-0.2) node(dx2) {$\delta x$};

    \draw[red] (4.2, 0.715305982) node(dy1) {$\delta y$};
    \draw[purple] (4.2, 1.94440325) node(dy2) {$\delta y$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to see you managed to do it yourself. You can check out [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/526633/73317) for ideas. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably less complete, it seems simpler to me when using the intersection module,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\usepackage{SIunitx}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-2,0) -- (4,0) coordinate(ffh) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) coordinate(ffv) node[above] {$y$};
    \draw[scale=1,domain=-2:2.5,smooth,variable=\x,blue,name path=Fx] plot ({\x},{(e^\x) / 4});

\def\dx{0.2}

\draw[dashed,red,thin,name path=V1] (0.5,0)coordinate(h1) --++(0,2);
\draw[dashed,red,thin,name path=V2] ($(h1)+(\dx,0)$) coordinate(h2) --++(0,2);
\draw[red]  ($(h1)+(0,-0.5em)$) -- node[below]{$\delta x$}($(h2)+(0,-0.5em)$) ;
\coordinate[name intersections={of=Fx and V1, by=i1}];
\draw (i1) --(i1-|ffh)coordinate(v1);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=Fx and V2, by=i2}];
\draw (i2) --(i2-|ffh)coordinate(v2);
\draw[red] (v1) --node[right]{$\delta y$} (v2);

\draw[dashed,red,thin,name path=V1] (1.5,0)coordinate(h1) --++(0,2);
\draw[dashed,red,thin,name path=V2] ($(h1)+(\dx,0)$) coordinate(h2) --++(0,2);
\draw[red]  ($(h1)+(0,-0.5em)$) -- node[below]{$\delta x$}($(h2)+(0,-0.5em)$) ;
\coordinate[name intersections={of=Fx and V1, by=i1}];
\draw (i1) --(i1-|ffh)coordinate(v1);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=Fx and V2, by=i2}];
\draw (i2) --(i2-|ffh)coordinate(v2);
\draw[red] (v1) --node[right]{$\delta y$} (v2);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]